# How to get the required response header from Beanshell processor for Jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter

how to get the required header from response header ?

i know we get all the response header this way 
`ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseHeaders();`

but i have 2 set-cookie values in my response headers

ex:

```
set-cookie: _csrf=XSASEDDDS;path=/`
set-cookie: X-MY-CSRF=ABcnsfdgsg;path=/`
```

i tried regular expression extractor as well but its not working ,am wondering do i have to change the regex

```
Apply to: Main sample only
Field to check: Response Headers
Reference Name: csrfToken
Regular Expression: set-cookie: X-MY-CSRF=(.+?);
Template: $1$
```

i need help to extract the `X-MY-CSRF` value and set it to user variable or global variable.

in jmeter we have 2nd occurrence option , so if i use this `regex` `set-cookie:\s+(.+)` with 2nd occurrence option i am able to get `X-MY-CSRF=ABcnsfdgsg;path=/` this value but not able to extract the `X-MY-CSRF`

Comment: If you can find and replace you could capture the first part in a group and then match the part that you want to replace and use the group in the replacement `(set-cookie: X-MY-CSRF=)[^;\n]+` https://regex101.com/r/pdW6gu/1

Comment: in jmeter we have 2nd occurrence option , so if i use `set-cookie:\s+(.+)` with 2nd occurrence option i am able to get `X-MY-CSRF=ABcnsfdgsg;path=/` this value but not able to extract the `X-MY-CSRF`

Comment: Try `set-cookie: X-MY-CSRF=([^;\n]+)` as the second occurence which will match the same as your pattern `set-cookie: X-MY-CSRF=(.+?);` only the ending `;` is not mandatory.

Comment: yaaaaaayyyyyyyyy ... its working with `X-MY-CSRF=(.+?);` but need to change to 1st occurrence

Comment: thank you @Thefourthbird